# Is there a commonly-accepted book or a site that explains the history-of-everything?

Tags: ancient-history, middle-ages

I don't know if i am allowed to post such question however i want a e-book or a site where i can start to understand the civilization and how it started. i mean i know a lot of ancient historic information but i am not sure if its correct. does the Mayans and the Aztecs lived in the north america ? does the vikings and Celts lived in the region of England ? is it true the Phoenician reached the north of america ? why Rome empire fall ? why Arab empire fall? why the Mongolia fall ?.. does the Egyptians took the pyramid architect from the aztecs ? or coincidence the discovered the same geometry? 
I am seeking for a e-book or a site where briefly talk about civilization.

Comment: "The Times Complete History of the World" by
Richard Overy is the most comprehensive, authoritative and accessible work on world history available today.  The book has all the answers you want and, therefore, there you can also learn how to capitalize "i" and how to capitalize any first letter of a sentence: "a", "b", etc.

Comment: @Carlo_R. you should just write the answer.  This Q is already mildly off-topic due to the kind of solicitation of discussion that it makes.

Comment: Not strictly a history book, but you may enjoy [Jared Diamond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jared_diamond)'s *Guns, Germs, and Steel*. I certainly did and it won e.g. the Pulitzer Prize.

Comment: Wikipedia is probably the most comprehensive, accessible, and affordable work on general history that you're going to find.

Comment: @joe how can i start ?

Comment: Read a little bit about each of your questions there, and let your interests take you wherever you want!  Want to know about the Mayans and Aztecs?  Start with their Wikipedia articles.  Want to know about the Vikings?  Read their Wikipedia article.  It won't have all the facts, but it's a pretty darn good introduction.  Then, when you have a specific question that Wikipedia can't help with, come back here and we'll be happy to help!

Comment: I'd recommend "1066 and All That" if you want to start with England. If you want a more universal outlook, I'd recommend the Barenaked Ladies song. Just to clarify, do you want a book that explores common themes and issues affecting many civilisations (like Jared Diamond's) or an absolutely gigantic history book? Anyway, you have lots of questions. Why not separate them out, do a bit of research on them individually using wikipedia maybe, and ask them on stack exchange. :D

Comment: @Joe if you post this as an answer i would accept because i guess this is what am looking for i will try to use wikipedia and start to find answers of my questions there and maybe later on i can choose a specific book because there are alot. one more last question which civilization you advice me to start? with aztec or Egyptians ? which civ is know to exist first ?

Comment: @NathanCooper no common themes to understand civilizations more. I am not looking through really detailed history

Comment: @MMD The thing is there are a lot of themes that pervade history, any in particular?

Comment: @NathanCooper well I like to understand how civilizations expanded and evolved , how empires rose and then how they fell.

Comment: Questions soliciting recommendations are off-topic per the [FAQ].

Comment: Luke's right, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a commonly-accepted book or a site that explains the history-of-everything?

No.  Nor will there ever be one.  The reductionism required to explain "everything," even if we limit that to the physical remains of cultural records of humanity plus the textual remains of humanity, no.  To make such an account fit within the 300-900 page limit of most books would require a summary tone that would reduce the "records of the past" to mere finger puppets for the author's ideological position.

However, there are books that try anyway, and provide something of a "pastiche" or a "whistle-stop" account of how first world westerners view reality.  Admittedly here you're getting first world westerner ideology, rather than records of the past, but the better kinds of this text cite their sources or provide a bibliography for further reading.

Most "World History 1" textbooks will cover this.  As will the wonderful "Cartoon History of the Universe" Parts 1-3.

Such surveys aren't real history, however.  They should be treated like encyclopaedia articles as the first aid to research, not as the end point.

> I am seeking for a e-book or a site where briefly talk about civilization.

You want an archaeology text book, giving that civilisation (the living in cities) predates literacy.